# copy xml nodes to new document in Java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I've been working on this all day and cant find a solution!

I want to read an xml

```
<test>
    <data></data>
</test>
```

and edit certain data values, which i can do and save fine.

But i want to get these changed values and add them to a new document, before changing the values again. So i end up with in a new document

```
<test>
    <data></data>
</test>
<test>
    <data></data>
</test>
```

I can create an ArrayList of nodes using this code

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tx   = tfactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(testDoc);
DOMResult output = new DOMResult();
tx.transform(source,output);
nodes.add(output.getNode());
```

So i now have an ArrayList of nodes that each have unique data edited from the template, but i cant seem to write them out to a new blank document. this is what i have currently

```
for (Node n:nodes){
    Element root = templateDoc.getDocumentElement();
    Node copyNode = templateDoc.importNode(n, true);
    root.appendChild(copyNode);
}
```

Trying to write out to templateDoc

Hope someone can help!

Answer (score 0):

A valid XML document may only have exactly one [root element](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_element). If `<test>` is the root element, you cannot have two `<test>` elements in the root. You would need something like this:

```
<tests>
 <test>
  <data>...</data>
 </test>
 <test>
  <data>...</data>
 </test>
</tests>
```

Comment: ahh ok, i do actually have another root element that i need to import, but i was trying to get this to work first, thanks